# Python: Name error in regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have been working on some RegEx code for HTML. I use beautiful for the mist part and needed some RegEx for some parts.

Here is the code:

```
`import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
lll=''
f=open('n.txt','w')
u='http://fortune.com/2015/12/31/wall-street-boutiques-did-well/'
r=urllib.request.urlopen(u)
s=BeautifulSoup(r.read(),'html.parser')
x=s.findAll('p')
print(r.read())
for p in x:
        l=str(p)
        ll=re.findall('<p>(.*)<a .*>',l)
        for t in ll:
                l1=t
        ln=re.findall('<a .*>(.*)</a>',l)
        for t in ln:
                l2=t
        lnn=re.findall('</a>(.*)</p>',l)
        for t in ll:
                l3=t
        lll= str(lll)+str(ll)+str(l2)+str(l3)`
```

But I am getting this, why?

```
lll= str(lll)+str(l1)+str(l2)+str(l3)
NameError: name 'l1' is not defined
```

Comment: Terrible variable  names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.findall('<p>(.*)<a .*>',l)` didn't find any matches, so `ll` is `[]`, which means that `for t in ll:` looped zero times, which means that the assignment `l1=t` never happened.

Double-check your regex and correct it so that it matches the content you're applying it to.

Comment: I think regex should be `'<p>(.*)<a [^>]*>'` or lazy `'<p>(.*)<a .*?>'`

Comment: `re.findall('<p>(.*)<a .*>', '<p>hello<a href="why">')` produces `['hello']`, so I don't know that that's it. It's probably a good idea, so that the regex doesn't match from the first `p` tag all the way to the last `a` tag (unless that's what OP wants), but the current regex shouldn't result in this particular problem given a proper matching content string.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using Beautifulsoup then why to use regex.I only showed how to achieve your desired output (i.e. `lll`) if i got you correct.

I am in Python 2.7 so i modified some of your code- This code extracts what inside `a` tag and what inside `p` tag and prints accordingly.

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

u='http://fortune.com/2015/12/31/wall-street-boutiques-did-well/'
r=urlopen(u)
s=BeautifulSoup(r.read(),'html.parser')
x=s.findAll('p')
for i in x:
    if len(i.select('a'))>0:
        print "Inside a {0}".format(''.join([j.text.encode('utf-8') for j in i.select('a')]))
    else:
        print "Inside p {0}".format(i.text.encode('utf-8'))
```

Output-

```
Inside p ┬⌐ 2016 Time Inc. All rights reserved.
Inside p In 2015 on Wall Street it appeared that it wasnΓÇÖt the size of the dog in the fight that mattered.
Inside a over $5 trillion of mergers
Inside p Indeed, on nearly all of the biggest deals of the year, Wall StreetΓÇÖs smaller firms nabbed key roles. On PfizerΓÇÖs $160 billion takeover of Allergan, which was the biggest announced acquisition of the year, Centerview Partners, a firm formed by ex-UBS banker Blair Effron and merger titan Robert A. Pruzan less than 10 years ago (currently with about 30 bankers), and Guggeheim Partners, another firm generally considered one of Wall StreetΓÇÖs so-called M&A boutiques, were advisors. Robey Warshaw, an advisory firm formed in spring 2014 with only nine bankers, according to reports, was an advisor on both Anheuser-Busch InBevΓÇÖs takeover of SABMiller and Royal Dutch ShellΓÇÖs announced deal to buy BG Group, which was the second and third largest deals of the year, respectively.
Inside a 
gs


jpm


Inside p Still the boutiquesΓÇÖ share is twice as high as what they took in 2008, according to Dealogic, which defines ΓÇ£boutiquesΓÇ¥ as financial firms with less than 1000 employees which make more than 80% of their revenue from advising on corporate combinations.
Inside p (Dealogic actually excludes Allen & Co. and Guggenheim, because they have sizable stock market businesses, suggesting the results for boutiques should have been even higher.)
Inside p This share has grown steadily since the financial crisis. But market share gains of the smaller firms are particularly surprising this year. Most large deals require financing. So you would expect the big banks to land most of the key roles. But that wasnΓÇÖt the case this year.
Inside p Indeed, about a decade ago, it was believed that the large banks, like Bank of America, Citigroup and JPMorgan Chase, would take an increasingly larger share of the mergers and acquisition by offering cheap loans in return for prized roles on M&A transactions. M&A advisory work is some of the most lucrative on Wall Street. But the financial crisis gave big banks a bad rap. Some clients thought the banks were putting their own interest first, and were turned off by the big banksΓÇÖ ΓÇ£cross-sellΓÇ¥ tactics. As a result, small firms that donΓÇÖt suffer from that stigma have been able to land roles on huge deals. Boutiques also donΓÇÖt have the same regulatory red tape as large banks. WhatΓÇÖs more, some bankers say the advisory job is simply more fun, and, as a result, many boutiques have pulled successful bankers away from behemoths.
Inside p But thereΓÇÖs a downside, though. Unlike large banks, these firms donΓÇÖt have other revenue streams to fall back on when mergers take an inevitable downturn. They may find that they, too, have to grow into other banking areas. Also itΓÇÖs harder to make money when the M&A market turns if a bank depends solely on a few big deals. After all, big deals pay more in fees proportionately, despite that advising small deals requires about the same amount of staff. A firm of a few hundred advisors can either live on a handful of large deals or dozens of small ones.
Inside a 
ghl.........................................
....................................................
```